# What does "meaning" mean in Whitehead and Russell's PM?

Tags: math-history, philosophy

In Principia Mathematica's Introduction, there is a definition for "incomplete" symbol:

> By an "incomplete" symbol we mean a symbol which is not supposed to
>   have any meaning in isolation, but is only defined in certain
>   contexts.  -- Chapter III, Principia Mathematica, 1st edition, page 69.

I am not sure what "meaning" means in this definition. Judging by the passage that follows, I guess if a symbol has a "meaning," that symbol stands for an object, like "Socrates" stands for a certain man. As a matter of fact, in Russell's *An Inquiry of Meaning and Truth,* the meaning of an object-word is the thing it stands for. Please let me know if "meaning" in PM has the same definition as in *An Inquiry of Meaning and Truth.* Thanks.

Comment: Reminds me the classical ramble of Michael Palin, http://youtu.be/bDK2zdHBX3Q?t=1m37s

Comment: hi George , you managed to do it completely the wrong way around, you ask the technical mathematical questions at philosophy and the philosophical here, better post them all at this forum i think. (and copy them to philforums if you cannot get your answr here)

Comment: Hi @Willemien, Several people have told me that. The two asked in Phil were the first two. After that I moved everything to here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Russell is developing his [theory of descriptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_descriptions) here. Roughly, he takes an "incomplete symbol" to be one that does not refer -- one that does not have a denotation in the way that proper names do. So, for example, the expression "the author of *Waverley*" -- according to Russell's theory -- does not *denote*; you cannot ask what its referent is. (EDIT 2: Russell does use the notation $\psi(\iota x\phi (x))$, but this doesn't mean that $\iota x\phi(x)$ denotes an object that can serve as the argument of $\psi(y)$, because $\psi(\iota x\phi(x))$ is really shorthand for $\exists x(\phi(x)\land\forall y(\phi(y)\rightarrow y=x)\land \psi(x))$.)

So noun phrases like "the author of *Waverley*," or "the more famous author of Principia Mathematica," cannot be thought of as proper names; and since Russell thinks of "meaning" in terms of reference, the expression cannot be said to have a meaning "in isolation." (One reason Russell makes this argument is to help explain how to formalize language about objects that don't exist, e.g. "the present King of France is bald" or "the greatest prime number.") Only in a sentence like "Scott is the author of *Waverley*" does the expression acquire a referent: that is what he means by the meaning only being "defined in certain contexts." In short, some expressions that *look* like object-words or proper names -- i.e., expressions that *look* like they refer (to an object) -- actually turn out not to be, if you're careful about the logical analysis.

Whether or not you are a proponent of the Russellian theory of definite descriptions, the mathematical examples Russell gives at the beginning of chapter 3 should not be taken too seriously. He says, for example, that the symbol $\frac{d}{dx}$ should be thought of as an incomplete symbol -- that it should not be thought of as having a denotation or referent by itself, when it isn't "completed" by a function symbol: e.g $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$.

To a contemporary mathematician, though, this might sound silly. A contemporary mathematician would likely say that $\frac{d}{dx}$ denotes a certain operator on a function space (e.g. the space of smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$). Of course, there may be some ambiguity about which function space is meant, but that doesn't pose much of a problem: it is usually clear from context which space of functions one is working over.

Comment: This is a good answer; but I think that there are still "incomplete symbols" in modern mathematics, i.e., not all incomplete symbols are operators.  For instance, the symbol "(".

Comment: I didn't say there weren't incomplete symbols in modern mathematics, or that every incomplete symbol is an operator. I said Russell's examples ($\int_a^b$ and $\nabla^2$) shouldn't be taken too seriously.

Comment: After some brooding, I think "the x that satisfies $ \phi(x) $" by itself does not represent one of the individual objects that can be arguments to $ \phi(x) $. In other words, the individual objects that can be arguments to $ \phi(x) $ are what PM means by "meanings" in this context, as is represented by single small Latin letters.

Comment: whoever edited my post to include the sentence "An "incomplete symbol" does not directly represent an object and, therefore, does not have meanings as single small Latin letters do." is wrong. incomplete symbols are not about "direct" and "indirection" representation, whatever that could mean. I'm deleting the sentence and rejecting the change.

Comment: @GeorgeChen: yes, what Russell means by "meaning" is "the value of a variable" (to use a formulation Quine would later make more famous when he said "To be is to be the value of a variable"). And the value of a variable is an object.

Comment: No. The iota operator has an existential quantifier embedded in it. EDIT: well, you're thinking about PM, and I'm not. I think to a contemporary logician $\iota x\phi(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x(\phi(x)\land\forall y(\phi(y)\rightarrow y=x))$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: "the author of Waverley" does not contain "exists." If it does, it would have meaning by itself.

Comment: *Roughly, what "the author of Waverley" says is something like: "there exists an x such that x is the author of Waverley and, for all y, if y is the author of Waverley, then y=x.* That is absolutely wrong. "The author of Waverley" expresses no proposition, your alleged equivalent does express a proposition (that there is one and only one author of Waverley).

Comment: Yes, you're right; it does not express a proposition. I meant to give a flavor of what "the" contributes to the logical form of propositions containing definite descriptions, but you're right.

Comment: Most definitions I'm aware of for $\iota x\phi$ don't expand to anything; $y \in \iota x\phi$ does, and $\iota x\phi\in y$ does, but outside of an atomic sentence it has no clear expansion. At least this is the Quinean sense in which it's incomplete. The expansion you give above is one for $\exists !$, which I've never seen denoted with $\iota$ before.

Comment: @Malice: I assume you used $\iota$ in the place of $℩$. $℩$ means "the" in PM. $\iota'x$  in PM represents the class whose only member is x.

Comment: "The x satisfying ϕ(x) exists" is represented by " E!(℩x)(ϕ(x)"; "the x such that ϕ(x) " is "(℩x)(ϕx)." Only the latter, which does not mention existence, has no meaning. * To type inverted iota: push cntl_shift U, then type 02129.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: sorry about the confusion. I finally figured out how to type inverted iota: $ u02129 $

Comment: @PeterSmith, Malice: I agree I was misexplaining the $\iota$ operator. But I also don't understand why we shouldn't think of $(\iota x)\phi(x)$ as standing for an open formula, say $\phi(x)\land\forall y(\phi(y)\rightarrow y=x)$. This does not express a proposition, because it is not a closed formula. Why not make this association to make perspicuous what "the" contributes to the logical structure of propositions with definite descriptions?

Comment: Yeah, I was just using what was used above me because I couldn't remember the latex for the other thing! I usually use $\imath$, push come to shove.

@symplectomorphic: Because $z\in\phi(x)\wedge\forall y(\phi(y)\to y=x)$ is ill-formed, as is $\phi(x)\wedge\forall y(\phi(y)\to y=x)\in z$. Descriptions are meant to act sort of like constants, syntactically, but giving it an expansion outside of a sentential context makes for the above. Further, you can quantify the $x$ in your proposed expansion, whereas $\imath x\phi(x)$ is a closed term.

Comment: (And I use $\in$ as my example, but there's nothing special here about that language.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with usages like "$y\in\iota x\phi(x)$." Is this just an abbreviation for $\exists x(\phi(x)\land\forall y(\phi(y)\rightarrow y=x))\land y\in x$, in the same way that $\psi(\iota x\phi(x))$ is just an abbreviation for $\exists x(\phi(x)\land\forall y(\phi(y)\rightarrow y=x)\land\psi(x))$? I guess what I'm really getting at is the inability of the Russellian theory to explain the syntactic similarity between "The F" and "The F is G" in natural language. David Kaplan gave an argument along these lines, I think.

Comment: Yes, same sort of expansion. I guess I don't see what it is you're trying to get at with it as an open formula; what specifically is the syntactic similarity in question, and how does Russel's theory of descriptions fail it?

Comment: This might be getting off topic, actually; my original point was a syntactic one, and this is a much more involved question.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I agree that $\frac{d}{dx}$ has meanings. It is a relation of $f'(x)$ to $f(x)$. And symbols in PM that stand for relations definitely have meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Following your own answer, recall that [page 66] :

> By an "incomplete" symbol we mean a symbol which is not supposed to have any meaning in isolation, but is only defined in certain contexts.

The issue is similar to that of *terms* [i.e.names] without denotation.

Basically, the "philosophy of meaning" of PM is based on *propositions* which "speak of" facts: the "ideal" language of PM's logic must express only *true* or *false* propositions.

Due to the paradoxes, R&W - in order to avoid the risk of propositions which are not true nor false - introduce the concept of "meaningless" expression. In their system, a menaingless proposition is detected by the fact that it violates syntactic constraints (see: *types theory*).

The paradigmatic case of "incomplete" symbol is that of *definite descriptions*, like :

> the King of France is bald.

What is the meaning of the above proposition if there is **no** King of France ?

The solution Russell discovered was based on the well know paraphrase :

> $(\exists x) (king_F(x) \land bald(x)) \land (\forall y)[(king_F(y) \land bald(y)) \rightarrow x = y]$.

Thus, in conclusion, if there is **no** King of France, the left conjunct is *false*, so that the complete sentence is *false*. We have found a way to give "meaning" to an expression also when it "seemingly" includes a non-denoting term.

Russell's solution is : circumvent the necessity of a term to safeguard "compositionalty" of meaning (i.e.the meaning or truth-value of the complete expression is based on the meaning of its components).

All this "machinery" is used in PM for *classes* [page 71] :

> The symbols for classes, like those for descriptions, are, in our system, incomplete symbols: their uses are defined, but they themselves are not assumed to mean anything at all. That is to say, the uses of such symbols are so defined that, when the *definiens* is substituted for the *definiendum*, there no longer remains any symbol which could be supposed to represent a class. Thus classes, so far as we introduce them, are merely symbolic or linguistic conveniences, not genuine objects as their members are if they are
>   individuals.

In other way, also *class* terms (i.e."modern" *set* terms : $\alpha = \{ x : \phi x \}$) like $\alpha = \hat{x} \phi x$, are "eliminated" in the same way, because non-denoting.

Comment: Excellent point, @Mauro. The more I consider this question, the more I get to grasp the philosophy aspect of this book.

Comment: I just learnt that PM cannot prove that there are more than two individuals in the world but sees it unnecessary to postulate that there are more than two. This makes me wonder what meaningful symbols in PM really stand for.

Comment: It seems that authors had "real things" in the back of their heads.

Comment: Russell commented decades later that things are arbitrary and that counting, number, and mathematics like art and music are man-made beauties. But here and now I just want figure out what they were thinking in 1910.

Comment: My mistake. One, not two. In the summary of *24, under*24.1 "Our primitive propositions do not require the existence of more than one individual

Comment: @GeorgeChen - I think there are different aspects: from the "logical" point of view, as in modern semantics for f-o logic, we need a non-empty domain in order to define an interpretation (but there are exceptions; see [Free Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/)). In order to license the inference from $\forall xP(x)$ to $\exists xP(x)$ we need "at least one object" in the "universe of discourse". The PM's *ontology* was (I think) mainly Russell's; he changed ideas during his long life, but at the time of PM ... 1/2

Comment: @GeorgeChen - ... he "believed" in a very "crowded" universe: individuals, propositional functions and more. The problem is that in order to "reconstruct" a plausible mathematical universe, we (as  W&R did) like the *infinite*. Thus, they have to *postulate* the existence of infinite *individuals* (see *Axiom of Infinity* in [Principia Mathematica](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/)) but still have problems with "higher" mathematical objects, due to the types theory's restrictions. Then, [Axiom of reducibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_reducibility). 2/2

Comment: See middle of page 69, "The round square doesn't exist." It seems that they believe the grammatical subject either represent a real object or disappears after analysis. It seems that, in 1910, by "individuals" they mean real objects in the world.

Comment: In that case, I understand why class is an incomplete symbol.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - about the "round sqaure", we must consider that Russell, before PM, criticized Meinong's theory according to which there where "real" existing objects (like me and you) and "subsisting" ones (like the round square): this in order to have a "referent" for all "names" in subject position into sentences. This "silly" idea was discussed (I suppose has supporters also today) but R in conclusion decided that there is only one "type" of beings: the existent one. I developed the "definite descripton" analisys to explain the "strange" case of non denoting "subjects".

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro, for providing the historical context. This will tackle Parmenides' puzzle: "There can be no thought corresponding to a name that is not the name of something real.

Comment: Types are classes, therefore symbols for types are also incomplete. 1. For first order functions, only individuals can be meaningful arguments. 2. For higher order predictive functions of one variable, only members of the type next below can be meaningful arguments although these members themselves are represented by incomplete symbols. That's all the meaningful things I can enumerate at this point.

Comment: You wrote "Basically, the "philosophy of meaning" of PM is based on propositions which "speak of" facts: the "ideal" language of PM's logic must express only true or false propositions." --I think that is the answer. Please give me some more time to think about.

Comment: It is a major theme in Russell's later work that a proposition must be either true or false in virtue of **facts**, otherwise it is meaningless. This is probably an implicit ground rule in 1st ed of PM regarding meanings.

Comment: When Shakespeare says that Hamlet was prince of Danmark, is he speaking nonsense like Edward Lear's poems?